# "two ways" Reclass QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, slope, reclassify

I'm a forestry technician and I've one question dealing with forest road planning... in order to calculate areas that can be cover by a specific machine (with a given work distance) I do as follow:

- "proximity" routine to calculate distance from road network;
- ratio between proximity output and a raster containing the cosine of slope angle in order to create a "orographic distance" raster,
- reclass of the output in served areas and not served areas, for example considering tractor equipped with forest winch served areas are all zones with distance from road till 80 m (work distance), distances greater than 80 m define instead not served areas...

Now I need to define two different work distances, one for uphill and one for downhill extraction... is there a way to do that directly with reclass or other QGIS tools?

At this moment I create two different rasters for uphill and downhill and manually clip them according to slope morphology.